# Cannot find declaration of getters generated for class fields by lombok when press ctrl+B (Android Studio 4.1.2)

Tags: android, android-studio, declaration

I created a class and used @Data(lombok) to generate getters for fields,like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class People{
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Then I used `new People().getName();` to get the name value,the program build successful and run normally,but when I press ctrl+B to find delcaration it can't go to the "People" class and the code color is red.
I tried to invalidate caches,restart android studio,reinstall android studio,but was not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my Android Studio don't install lombok plugin, after I installed the lombok plugin,the problem was solved.